# Adding Views with Equal Width to Superview - Autolayout iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, autolayout

I have 3 uiviews which is added to parent view. i want the views (subviews) should have equal width in Portrait and Landscape. You can see three views share equal width in portrait but the centerview takes more space in Landscape. How to make equal width in Landscape.

Landscape:

[image]

Portrait:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the task is very trivial, you just have to set all horizontal edge relationships (e.g. `view1.left = superview.left`, `view2.left = view1.right`, `view3.left = view2.right` and `view3.right = superview.right`) as well as make all three views' width equal.

Also, don't forget to make vertical constraints, so vertical positions and heights could be calculated.